# Why "Sqoop import --query ..." inserts multiple rows when only one row should be inserted?

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

I am getting 'Hands-on-Experience' with hadoop, sqoop, pig, flume, ...

In my local `mysql` schema I have a table called `Employee` with following structure:

```
`emp_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
`first_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL
`last_name` varchar(30) NOT NULL
`create_date` datetime NOT NULL
```

Employee table had four rows.

I ran the following sqoop command:

```
sqoop --options-file import.txt \
--query "select 1 as emp_id, 'Barry' as first_name, 'Williams' as last_name, '2016-04-20 15:41:00' as create_date from test.Employee where \$CONDITIONS" \
--target-dir /user/<username>/Employee  \
--split-by emp_id \
-m 1
```

In the `sqoop` command `select ...` has data for only one row.
So, only one row should be inserted.

Result of the `sqoop` command:

When I ran following command:

```
hdfs dfs -cat /user/<username>/Employee/part-m-00000
```

I got this:

```
1,Barry,Williams,2016-04-20 15:41:00
1,Barry,Williams,2016-04-20 15:41:00
1,Barry,Williams,2016-04-20 15:41:00
1,Barry,Williams,2016-04-20 15:41:00
```

Questions:

```
1) Why were four rows inserted instead of one?
2) Is it because there were four rows in the table when the `sqoop` command ran? 
3) Is this a bug?
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not a bug. You are querying in wrong way.
You need to add LIMIT to your sql query. Updated query will look like following:

```
sqoop --options-file import.txt \
--query "select 1 as emp_id, 'Barry' as first_name, 'Williams' as last_name, '2016-04-20 15:41:00' as create_date from test.Employee  LIMIT 1 where \$CONDITIONS" \
--target-dir /user/<username>/Employee  \
--split-by emp_id \
-m 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is a bug but this is interesting, I never tried to execute sqoop command that way.

`--split-by` the specified column (primary key) is used by sqoop to split work units.

`-m 1` is forcing sqoop to use only 1 mapper.

You have a free form query import, based on the query sqoop should create only 1 row. My assumption is that you have both `--split-by` & `-m 1` options/arguments passed to the scoop; maybe `--split-by` takes precedence over `-m`. Usually sqoop executes with 4 mappers only job when `-m` are not specified, I guess each mapper created 1 row of hardcoded fields in the sql statement.

Try your sqoop command without the `--split-by` argument.

Comment: `split-by` option was removed. 
I used `-m 1` option and got same results -- 4 rows were inserted. I used `--num-mappers 1` option and got the same result.

So, I tried this:
I added for four more rows to `mysql` table and ran `sqoop` command again. Now, 8 rows were inserted!

Answer (score 0):

I dont know why you are getting 4 records. I am getting 1 record only in my system. Please add Limit 1 at the end of select... query after WHERE $CONDITIONS and see. hope this may work

Answer (score 0):

Sqoop is working fine. Try to run this query against the database and you will see the output will be equal to the number of rows in that table.